# How can I get an element' attribute value and store it in a variable( for reuse purpose)in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress

```
cy.get('.wishlist__articleList').eq(0).invoke('attr', 'data-wishlist-entry-id').then(Aelement => {
      // 'prop()' method is used to get the attribute value.
     
      let val  = cy.wrap(Aelement).text()
      cy.log(val)

     })
```

As shown in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LzzX.png), I want to get this number '11140805' and store it in a variable like `val`.

Comment: please be sure to make your question clear and well structured :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Alias `as` to save the value of the attribute and then use it later on, something like this. Also to extract just the number you have to use the javascript `split` method.

```js
cy.get('.wishlist__articleList')
  .eq(0)
  .invoke('attr', 'data-wishlist-entry-id')
  .as('dataWishlistEntryIdValue')

cy.get('@dataWishlistEntryIdValue').then((val) => {
  //Access value here
  cy.log(val.split(',')[0]) //prints 11140805 as a string
  cy.log(+val.split(',')[0]) //prints 11140805 as a number
})
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Alapan's answer: using a `Cypress.env` variable, which will allow you to use the variable more similarly to a traditional JS variable.

```js
cy.get('.wishlist__articleList')
  .eq(0)
  .invoke('attr', 'data-wishlist-entry-id')
  .then((attr) => {
    Cypress.env('foo', attr);
  });

cy.get('some-element').should('have.text', Cypress.env('foo'));
```